# What is the release schedule for Lubuntu Alternate patch releases?

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, system, alternate

The [Lubuntu Alternate ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO) does not always get released simultaneously with the rest of the ISO's. For example, according to [TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule), as of April 30th, 2015, the following releases should be available:

- 14.04(.0) LTS, released on April 17th, 2014
- 14.04.1, released on July 24th, 2014
- 14.04.2, released on February 19th, 2015

In reality, only 14.04 and 14.04.1 Lubuntu Alternate images are available [on the archives](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/). Judging by the files' timestamps, they were released on schedule, as well as the desktop 14.04.2 variants. However, the Alternate variants aren't there. When, if at all, can we expect the Alternate images to appear?

When I look at [the corresponding directory](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/) for 12.04 LTS, I see no patch releases at all, although, according to [the release schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseSchedule), there should be 4 already. I have no particular interest in the older LTS version, but I'd like to understand: what can I expect; what is the guiding principle here?

Comment: The 14.04.2 patch release differs from the previous ones in that it not only has  all the updates baked in; it installs the newer kernel and xorg version, which doesn't get installed by default when updating from the older patch release. I wonder if this has something to do with the fact that 14.04.2 Alternate has not been released?

Answer (score 0):

There were significant, insurmountable challenges faced with debian-installer in the transition from tasks to metapackages that led to the decision to skip the alternative ISO for Trusty 14.04.2. [The release press release explains in additional detail](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2015-February/009348.html). To my knowledge, there are no plans to go back and generate alternatives for that release.

If installation from the desktop installer is not possible on your system (or otherwise not desired), [please consider the mini ISO/netboot option](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall). If netboot wouldn't work, installing from a previous 14.04 alternate and upgrading will get you there.

Lubuntu lacks 12.04 patch releases because [Lubuntu 12.04 was not an LTS and is no longer supported](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/Lubuntu#Support).